# return same object after destructuring in function params

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

Let's say I have an Object

`var bar = {hi: 1, there: 2};`

I would like to, at the end of the function, return the same object that was passed while at the same time doing a destructuring assignment in the function param.

It might look like this:

```
function foo({hi, there}){
    //logic with variables "hi" and "there"
    return ...arguments;
}
```

and have the return value be the same as `bar;`
for obvious reasons the spread operator doesn't work in this context, but I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Name and destructure separately:

```
function foo(obj) {
    let {hi, there} = obj;
    // logic with variables "hi" and "there"
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was a way to do this w/o having that second line.

Comment: @anonrose: There’s nothing that avoids doing them separately. You can abuse a second parameter to get them on the same *line* with `function foo(obj, {hi, there} = obj)`, but I wouldn’t. Another fun quirk is `function foo({obj: {hi, there}, obj})` and `foo({obj: bar})`, but again…